# Why there are two DKIM signatures in email?

Tags: phoenix-framework, amazon-ses

I am trying to send an email using Phoneix and Amazon SES, using `bamboo` and `bamboo_ses`.
I have verified both email and domain on Amazon SES and added that (the same) DKIM record to the DNS.

I am setting an email like this:

```
email =
  new_email()
  |> to(recipient)
  |> Bamboo.Email.from({name, from})
  |> subject('Some Subject')
  |> text_body(body_text)
  |> put_header("Return-Path", from)
```

But every time I send email like this, on the other end I get two DKIM signatures, like this:

Signature 1 :

```
v=1;
a=rsa-sha256;
q=dns/txt;
c=relaxed/simple;
s=someletterssssssadasdsd;
d=mydomain.com;
t=123456789;
h=To:Subject:Mime-Version:From:Content-Type:Message-ID:Date;
bh=somelettersssssss=;
b=somelonglettersssss=
```

Signature 2 :

```
v=1;
a=rsa-sha256;
q=dns/txt;
c=relaxed/simple;
s=someletterssasdasddasdasd;
d=amazonses.com;
t=123456789;
h=To:Subject:Mime-Version:From:Content-Type:Message-ID:Date:Feedback-ID;
bh=somenumber=;
b=kq/somelongnumber=
```

Why is that? How I can overcome attaching that second signature, as when I try to send through amazon, I get only one (Signature 1), with my domain.

Comment: I'm not sure if helpful but the 2nd DKIM is added by Amazon SES automatically, I don't believe it can be removed and as per their docs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/troubleshoot-dkim.html) it says it can be ignored.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For some reason, everything worked as expected when I was using Amazon SMTP configuration to send emails using SES, but when I used API - I had the noted problem. But it works with SMTP so in a way, it is good for now, but the question is still open in a way.

Comment: @mattantley your response is the definitive answer for this question. Consider making it answer, so that Aleks can accept it, and you can earn the reputation you deserve.

Comment: Sadly, it is was more a hint that it is being added automatically. The solution in this case for me was to send it via SMTP protocol. That way only one signature was applied. The comment from @mattantley helped in a way to potentially move to another approach. I never managed to have only one signature when sending emails via API.

Answer (score 0):

Having multiple DKIM signatures is allowed according to [DMARC specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7489):

> Note that a single email can contain multiple DKIM signatures, and it is considered to be a DMARC "pass" if any DKIM signature is aligned and verifies.

In fact, Amazon SES always adds its own DKIM signature regardless of being sent via API or SMTP (I'm observing this now) and even for manually signed messages ([Amazon SES documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-email-authentication-dkim-manual.html)):

> Every message that you send by using Amazon SES contains a DKIM header that references a signing domain of amazonses.com ... [Even] if you manually sign your messages, your messages will include two DKIM headers: one for your domain, and the one that Amazon SES automatically creates for amazonses.com